# Is the Lie derivative of a conformal killing vector field along a parallel vector field still conformal Killing?

Tags: differential-geometry

A vector field $\xi$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is called conformal Killing if $L_{\xi}g=fg$ for some function $f$, where $L_{\xi}$ is the Lie derivative along $\xi$. And a vector field $T$ is parellel if $\nabla T=0$ for Riemann connection induce by $g$. Then the question is the following:

Is $L_T\xi$ still conformal Killing? If yes, how to prove it. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange.com! If you find the answer below completely meeting your expectations, please mark it as accepted so that the other users will know that the question is answered. If there are any issues with the answer, please leave comments under it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $L_{T} \xi = [T,\xi]$, we need to find $L_{[T, \xi]}g$.

Notice, that $L_{[T, \xi]} = [L_{T}, L_{\xi}]$ in the algebra of derivations on all tensor fields.

Thus, we can calculate:

$$
\begin{align}
L_{[T, \xi]}g &= [L_{T}, L_{\xi}]g \\
&= L_{T}L_{\xi}g - L_{\xi}L_{T}g \\
& = L_{T}(fg) \\
&= (L_{T} f) g + f L_{T} g \\
& = (Tf)g
\end{align}
$$

where we have used the product rule for the Lie derivative, and the fact that $L_T g = 0$ when $T$ is parallel w.r.t to the Levi-Civita connection of $g$.

Therefore, $L_{T}\xi$ is again a conformal Killing field.